# Can not use EMR vcores completely in spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using Amazon EMR cluster with master node as C3.4xLarge and 3 worker nodes (c3.8XLarge).
I am trying to submit a job

```
pyspark --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 17G
```

[image]

then we can see in the image that only 7 vCore are used of 94 vCore.

If i try to run

```
pyspark --num-executors 17 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 8G
```

then only 17 vCore are used of 94 vCore.

So how can i configure the total vcore used so that the cluster utilization is optimum.

[this](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) link gives details about the c3 instance of amazon EMR

Comment: I seem to be running into the same issue.